# Can we track weburl opened in trusted web activity..?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, android-customtabs, twa

I am working on an android app that open **trusted web activity**. but I want to **track url** which open in **TWA** for **analytic** reason. is their any way to track opening URL in **trusted web activity**? code which i written for TWA is only in the android manifest. I just copy-paste my android manifest file. just take a look.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dummy.work">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LauncherActivity"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity   

        android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.
        LauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/appName">

            <intent-filter>
                <category 
        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category 
          android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category 
          android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="beta.turms.in"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="beta.turms.in"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />

            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data

        android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="@string/launchUrl" />
            <meta-data


        android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.
        STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="use_browser_on_chromeOS"
            android:resource="@bool/useBrowserOnChromeOS" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/assetStatements" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

      <service

       android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.
             TrustedWebActivityService"
             android:enabled="@bool/enableNotification"
             android:exported="@bool/enableNotification">
             <intent-filter>
                <action 



         android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.
         TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY_SERVICE" />

                <category 
         android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data        

       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.
       default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
      android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

     </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Web Analytics tools (such as Google Analytics) should work as expected. I'm not sure if you want to know about a more specific tracking (eg: how many users are opening the page from the TWA). Can you add those details?

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually i want to fire facebook events based on url. is this possible in TWA

Comment: Do you want to fire facebook events using the native Facebook SDK?